# No Data in cells when opening older excel files in Office 2011 for OS 10.8

Tags: macos, ms-office, data

I have older excel files saved as xls. When I open them in Excel 2011 on my Mac with OS 10.8, I get all of the formatting but no data in the cells. This happens whether I double-click to open or open from within Excel. Files saved as xlsx are fine. I also tried reloading Microsoft Office, but that doesn't seem to work. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks